# How do I write SFINAE for copy-list-init in a return statement, in a portable way?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I'm trying to make the following function SFINAE-friendly:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename ...P>
T foo(P &&... params)
{
    return {std::forward<P>(params)...};
}
```

I can't put a `return` statement in a SFINAE context, but since this is an example of [*copy-list-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), I figured I could find a different example that is SFINAE-able.

There is `T({...})`, but [only GCC accepts it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:8,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:8,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:3),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+...P%3E%0AT+foo(P+%26%26...+params)%0Arequires+requires%7BT(%7Bstd::forward%3CP%3E(params)...%7D)%3B%7D%0A%7B%0A++++return+%7Bstd::forward%3CP%3E(params)...%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++A(int)+%7B%7D%0A++++A(const+A+%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A++++A+%26operator%3D(const+A+%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++foo%3Cstd::array%3CA,+3%3E%3E(1,+2,+3)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.37826370757182,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:g121,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:clang1400,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/10%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.621736292428196,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
template <typename T, typename ...P>
T foo(P &&... params)
requires requires{T({std::forward<P>(params)...});}
{
    return {std::forward<P>(params)...};
}
```

```
#include <array>

struct A
{
    A(int) {}
    A(const A &) = delete;
    A &operator=(const A &) = delete;
};

int main()
{
    foo<std::array<A, 3>>(1, 2, 3); // Error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of `std::array`.
}
```

There is also `foo({...})` (a function call). [GCC and Clang accept it, but MSVC rejects it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:11,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:3,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:11,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:3),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+accept(T)+noexcept%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+...P%3E%0AT+foo(P+%26%26...+params)%0Arequires+requires%7Baccept%3CT%3E(%7Bstd::forward%3CP%3E(params)...%7D)%3B%7D%0A%7B%0A++++return+%7Bstd::forward%3CP%3E(params)...%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++A(int)+%7B%7D%0A++++A(const+A+%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A++++A+%26operator%3D(const+A+%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++foo%3Cstd::array%3CA,+3%3E%3E(1,+2,+3)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:49.37826370757182,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:g121,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:clang1400,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/10%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.621736292428196,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4):

```
template <typename T>
void accept(T) noexcept;

template <typename T, typename ...P>
T foo(P &&... params)
requires requires{accept<T>({std::forward<P>(params)...});}
{
    return {std::forward<P>(params)...};
}
```

How do I work around the compiler bugs, and write this SFINAE in a portable way?

Comment: [msvc seems to create a temporary to move from when aggregate initializing an argument](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/n1noaGGMe) / [example 2](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/TTc3nqe8M), so copy elision doesn't happen making `accept<std::array<A, 3>>({1, 2, 3})` not compile. Changing to `accept<T&&>` makes it work by binding directly to the temporary that MSVC erroneously creates (And your first try should have been `T{ std::forward<P>(params)... }`,allowing explicit constructors too, and I think GCC is wrong for accepting `T({ params... })` which initializes a temporary to call the copy constr with)

Comment: I'm curious if either changing to `accept<T&&>` or declaring `accept(T&&) noexcept` solves this issue here. It seems to work for the test case you provided as well as the case when `A` has an `explicit` constructor. What are the case(s) where this does not do what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version [works](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:21,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:21,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:21,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:21,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Avoid+accept(const+T%26)+noexcept%3B%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+...P%3E%0AT+foo(P+%26%26...+params)%0Arequires+requires%7Baccept%3CT%3E(%7Bstd::forward%3CP%3E(params)...%7D)%3B%7D%0A%7B%0A++++return+%7Bstd::forward%3CP%3E(params)...%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%0Astruct+A%0A%7B%0A++++A(int)+%7B%7D%0A++++A(const+A+%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A++++A+%26operator%3D(const+A+%26)+%3D+delete%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++foo%3Cstd::array%3CA,+3%3E%3E(1,+2,+3)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.022465187119245,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:conformance,i:(compilers:!((compilerId:g121,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:clang1400,options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-Wall+-Wextra+-pedantic-errors%27),(compilerId:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27)),editorid:1,langId:c%2B%2B,libs:!()),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Conformance+Viewer+(Editor+%231)+3/10%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.64420147954744,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_latest_x64,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27/std:c%2B%2Blatest%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x64+msvc+v19.latest+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x64+msvc+v19.latest%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x64+msvc+v19.latest+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) if you take `const&` parameter in `accept`:

```
template <typename T>
void accept(const T&) noexcept;
```